# Solution of nonlinear heat equation decreases in time?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, heat-equation

Let $f$ be a smooth decreasing function which is non-negative and bounded above, and consider the heat equation on a smooth bounded domain
$$u_t - \Delta u = f(u)$$
with Dirichlet BCs and some initial data.

When can I say that $u$ is decreasing in time and how do I prove that?